# C# Keep form draggable when show another form using ShowDialog method

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have three projects (proj1, proj2, pro3). The proj1 (winforms) is where I integrate the others projects. The proj2 (in wpf, not important for this question, I thinks) have a window like  a menu of notifications which I want be always on top and be draggable. The proj3 (wpf too) have some windows with owner relations.

Proj1:

```
public FormGeral()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartMenu();
}

private void StartMenu()
{
    var wpfwindow = new Proj2.WindowController(this.pProperties, true);
    ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow);
    wpfwindow.Closed += wpfwindow_Closed;
    this.Activate();
}

private void buttonX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var wpfwindow = new Proj3.WindowInvoices(this.pProperties);
   ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow);
   wpfwindow.Show();
   wpfwindow.Closed += wpfwindow_Closed;
 }
```

In proj3, the WindowInvoices have a button like that:

```
private void ButtonAddInvoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowAddEditInvoice window = new WindowAddEditInvoice(this.PProperties, idModulo, null, true, null);
            window.Owner = this;
            window.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
```

When I first click to open WindowInvoices on Proj3, the menu on Proj2 works nice, on top and draggable. But when I open WindowAddEditInvoice on Proj3, the menu window on Proj2 isn't draggable. Pay attention to the use of Show or ShowDialog methods.

What is the best way to implement this behavior?

Comment: `ShowDialog` opens a modal form, one of the main characteristics is that it disables the previous form. If you want to keep the parent active (for dragging for example) you need to use `Show` and disable the elements you don't want to be active.

Comment: Hi @Alejandro, thanks for the answer. Once is two different projects isn't possible have some like two different paths? Make the menu window independent from windows from proj3?

Comment: It's not important that they're different projects, the problem is that `ShowDialog` is blocking to the parent form. You're making them dependent once you use it, but `Show` leaves them separate, at the price of having both enabled.